# Consulta com dados duplicados no MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Olá.

Estou com problemas para exibir resultado de um consulta no banco.

Tenho 2 tabelas

```
Tabela 1 - logs // logs do sistema
//user_id = são os usuários administrativos do sistema
//user_perfil = é o perfil do usuário que usa o sistema (cliente).

    id | user_id | user_perfil
    1  |    10   |   105
    2  |    10   |   106
    3  |    12   |   105
    4  |    12   |   104

    Tabela 2 - user
    id  | nome
    10  | Luiz
    11  | Renato
    12  | Marcio
```

Tenho uma tela que exibe o resultado através do ID do perfil do cliente, pelo GET, que busca as informações através de outra tabela que é o perfil do usuário, que exibe o nome e outras informações.

O detalhe aqui é exibir o log de acesso dos administradores, para saber quem já visualizou este perfil.
Para isso criei a tabela logs, que toda a vez que o administrador acesse esse perfil grava o user_id - do administrador e o user_perfil - do perfil cliente. grava unicamente, sem repetir.

A logica seria a seguinte, através do GET gera o ID do perfil, e grava no banco logs, id do administrador (session) e o ID Get do perfil.

Exibir somente quem viu, no meu caso com o while ele está exibindo todos os administradores, utilizei o GROUP BY, para não repetir os dados.

Gostaria de exibir o nome do administrador que visualizou o perfil do usuário.
Tentei fazer o while abaixo, mas não está rolando.
Não ocorre erro, ele exibe unicamente o nome de cada administrador.
Tipo o user Luiz visualizou o perfil 105 e 106, e Marcio visualizou 105 e 104, quando acessar o perfil 105 deveria exibir Luiz e Marcio, e perfil 106 somente Luiz, mas em todos os perfil esta exibindo Luiz, Marcio e Renato.

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado

Segue o while que fiz:

```
        $situacao_atual = $row_logs['user_id'];
        $result_logs = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$situacao_atual'";
        $result_logs = mysqli_query($conn, $result_logs);

        $row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_logs);
        //$row_logs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_logs);

        $iduser = $row_logs['user_perfil'];
          if($idcurriculo = $id){

                echo $row_usuarios['nome'];
            }
            else {echo "no";}        
 }
```

Comment: Porque esta executando duas vezes o `$row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_logs); $row_logs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_logs);`?

Comment: Olá, erro de comentário, deveria estar comentado o $row_logs, será editado a pergunta. obrigado

Answer (score 0):

o problema esta em seu Select use este select que resolve seu problema de trazer os nomes que visualizaram um determinado perfil

```
select nome from tab_log l where user_id = ?parametro join tab_user u on u.id = l.user_id
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte maneira, modifiquei a consulta e está funcionando corretamente.
 `$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE curriculo_id = $id";
 $result_log = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row_logs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_log)){
  $situacao_log = $row_logs['usuario_id'];
  $resultado_nome = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$situacao_log'";
  $result_nome = mysqli_query($conn, $resultado_nome);
  $row_nome = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_nome);`

Comment: Ótimo, eu sei bem SQL mas nao conheço PHP mas se resolveu seu problema ótimo, parabéns.